# no automatic black and white printing in microsoft 10

Tags: printing, microsoft-edge

Though my printer (HP) is set  at black and white for all, in Microsoft Edge, etc it prints in color unless I manually remember each time to change the setting!  It works automatically in internet explorer.  Lots of wasted ink!

Answer (score 1):

You set printer default settings in the Printer Properties.

1. Open the Search tool on your computer and type "Devices and Printers".
2. Open Devices and Printers.
3. Right click on your printer and select Printer Properties.
4. Change the values in the dialog to default to black and white or monochrome.
5. Click OK to save.

The next time you open a program and print to it, the default behavior will be to print black and white. If you wish to print color you'll still be able to select it on a per-document basis.

Comment: You need to do this in Printing Defaults, from Printer Properties > Advanced tab > Printing Defaults button.

Comment: That varies by printer @hdhondt. I believe HP printers have the advanced tab, but other brands/models vary.

Comment: I have never seen a printer that did not have the Advanced tab. It's the only place to set Defaults, enable Banner Pages, etc. See, for example https://i1.wp.com/techspeeder.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/Printer-Properties.png

Comment: I hadn't either for many years, but some drivers these days just use the settings in the Properties dialog as defaults, which is probably less confusing for some.